# MacBook Air 2011 only panics after an update attempt froze

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently bought a second-hand MacBook Air 2011 running perfectly on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) and a few weeks later I attempted to update it to El Capitan and it froze for about an hour. When I switched it OFF and ON again it showed a crash panic.

I have tried doing research about it and would get the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> methods but it does not go to the recovery mode screen or any of the bootable options that would usually be helpful when faced with such a problem.

Is there anyone who could help out? I even took it to the nearest repair shop and they told me it's an old model. I like to believe that there's more to it than that, there is an option.

Comment: What exactly does it do when you try to go to Recovery mode?

Comment: Can you create an El Capitan installation key from another Mac?
Otherwise to start in Internet Recovery mode, you must press the keys **alt+cmd+r** during boot. But this operation requires a firmware update on some older models. The different key combinations are listed here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255